# Pandas and data imputation from a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, 20, 4],
                   [3, 1, np.nan, 1],
                   [3, 1, 15, 1],
                   [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1],
                   [10, 1, 30, 4],
                   [50, 2, 35, 4],
                   [10, 1, 37, 4],
                   [40, 2, 30, 1]],
                  columns=list("ABCD"))
```

I want to fill the Nan values with their group means.
Towards that purpose, I run the following:

```
df_mean=df.groupby(["B","D"]).mean()
df_mean

        A     C
B   D       
1   1   3.0   15.0
    4   10.0  33.5
2   1   40.0  30.0
    4   50.0  27.5
```

Is there a way to fill the dataframe df with the values computed in df_mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a data science question and would therefore be better suited for stackoverflow stackexchange, but the following code should do what you're looking for:

```
df[["A", "C"]] = (
    df
    # create groups
    .groupby(["B", "D"])
    # transform the groups by filling na values with the group mean
    .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
)
```

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2 | 20 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 | 30 | 4 |
| 50 | 2 | 35 | 4 |
| 10 | 1 | 37 | 4 |
| 40 | 2 | 30 | 1 |

Comment: I must say it's not the first time one of your answers surprises me... Many thanks. It will take a bit for me to understand exactly how this is working. =D